# Mysql PDO/MySqli Connect From Linux Host

Tags: mysql, php, websites, html, visual-studio-code

My Database host and my website host are not the same.

I have created a few web applications on .NET with a **web.config** or **app.config** file where I could easily set a `machinekey` for the MySQL connection on a MySQL database for the web-farm.

This was very simple on .NET or Visual studio web application.

```
<system.web>
   <machineKey validationKey="C250127840E44F50A34824E348FC089A0DE6C60C3D0CF61A31AB01BCAB6AE3940C82648D2F085B1DECFA5204AD393A5810403DABED73002608AEF7231F29E6CB" decryptionKey="8A86EB63181EDD9439D664ACA990D07302F3280E6F6919B3" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
</system.web>
```

**However**

I am now creating a website for a GNU/Linux host. I am using the same Database and again, on testing, the connection is fine. However, when published, the MySQL connection is refused.

- I have a suspicion that it is again because of the web-farm, but
  there is no evidence of it.
- **I have allowed the host IP on remote-mysql.**
- **I have checked that the Host IP is not blocked on the MySQL host.**
- **I have checked the ports for the MySQL connection.(it works before publish).**
- **I have checked the user privileges on the MySQL username.**
- **I have also mailed the support guys on my MySQL host to see if there is anything on their side.**
- I have been sitting with this for a while, and its frustrating.

**Is there a way I can set the Machine key on this application/is it needed?**

If anyone suggest anything else I could check, or point me to a setting I may be missing, that would be MUCH appreciated.

Below is my connection, which DOES work when I run the application.

Publish to host, Connection refused.

```php
<?php

    $host = "server IP";
    $port = 3306;
    $user = "username";
    $password = "**********";
    $dbname = "mysql.table";

    $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

?>

<?php

 $host = 'DB_IP';
    $dbname = 'DB_Name';
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=DB_IP;dbname=DB_Name';
    $username = 'Username';
    $password = 'Password';

     try {
         $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
         echo "Connected to $dbname at $host successfully.";
     } catch (PDOException $pe) {
         die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
     }    

  ?>
```

**This is when I test the code:**

> Connected to mydb at IPADDRESS successfully.

**This is after publish to the host:**

> Could not connect to the database mydb :SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
>   Connection refused

**I am getting the same result with PDO and MySQLi.**

If anyone can please assist. I have been looking for answers for days now.

Comment: Beware. Mysql can be quite confusing. You can have accounts with the same name, but different networks and different passwords. Try this but ONLY for testing. This will open up the DB for the outside. If this works you have to remove and refine your remote access. 

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON database.*
TO 'user'@'%'
IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';

Comment: Hi there s1mmel.  Thank you so much for your suggestion.  I have done this already as well.  I am truly stumped on this.

Comment: I also tried the server address https://..  Same result.  Test code works.  Published code : connection refused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much for all the assistance.  It seems that the host I was using for my database for almost 4 years has decided to lock down the 3306 access to workbench and remote access.  No notification of this.

They have decided that the attack rate on the MySQL is too high.  Now only local host and same host websites work there.  This is strange though, because all my other projects and workbench still connect.  I have argued this with them, but they insist.

I will have to move the database elsewhere.

I did a test this morning on a different host. All worked perfectly.

Thanks again for all the assistance.